# Crear Migrations personalizadas en Laravel

Tags: laravel, migration

Cuando se crea una Migration nueva en Laravel, con el comando `php artisan make:migration`, esta tiene algunos campos por defecto: La clave primaria, llamada `id()` y los `campos created_at` y `updated_at` mediante `timestamps()`.

Los que me gustaría sería que, al crear una migration me aparecieran, por defecto, otros campos, como `created_by` y `last_updated_by`.

Supongo que habrá que modificar alguna plantilla en algún sitio, pero no tengo ni idea de donde.

Comment: Los campos que mencionas ¿además de `created_at` y `updated_at` o en lugar de?, por otro lado recuerda que es importante agregar aquello que hayas intentado aunque no funcione del todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes correr este comando

```
php artisan stub:publish
```

Esto te creará la carpeta stubs en la raiz del proyecto. Te permitirá modificar las plantillas de la migración en

```
stubs/migration.create.stub
O bien
stubs/migration.stub
```